# X mouse button control simulated keystrokes

Tags: mouse

I have mad my right click into the button f, but it only does f once when I click. I want it to act the same, so that I can also hold right click to act as hold f.

If that was hard to understand, sorry, but to make it simple:
The f key is a button in a game that acts as a parry when I click it and as a block when I hold it. I can only parry with my right click and it does not block when I hold.

Comment: How have you made the modification?

Answer (score 0):

The
[X-Mouse Button Control User Guide](http://vps.highrez.co.uk/downloads/X-Mouse%20Button%20Control%20User%20Guide.pdf)
has on page 7 the option of "Button Held (Time Dependent Actions)":

[image]

I don't use this product, but this option might be what you're looking for:
"Wait until the physical button is released before releasing the last timed action".